# 301 Redirect in .htaccess gives certificate warning on original URL first

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

My site has a certificate but it's not a wildcard certificate. So it's for example.com, not for *.example.com.

Not a problem I thought, I'll just redirect any visitor to the proper URL through mod_rewrite:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # Following two lines to strip machine name
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # Following two lines make sure the https version is always served
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]
```

Now, the redirect actually works. When someone types in https://www.example.com/page, he will eventually be redirected to https://example.com/page.

But...

The browser first displays a warning that https://www.example.com is insecure. Only when I add an exception, will it be redirected to https://example.com/page which does not give a certificate error...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. SSL negotiation occurs at the transport (TCP) level, not HTTP (even when using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) but the point is that the certificate is not valid for the requested domain. When the connection is initiated to `www.` the browser will request the certificate and compare the url with the `CN` in the cert and since it isn't there, it'll raise the alert.

To resolve this issue you will need a certificate that includes both ServerName and ServerAlias names. You could maybe try some DNS provider that offers DNS HTTP redirection, but getting a certificate is [quite easy](https://letsencrypt.org/) this days.